# How can I give a wet effect to my character mouth and eyelids

Tags: materials

I'm making a maned wolf and I'm trying to make a material for the eye lids and gum with this wet effect: [image]

[image]

but the effect I'm getting looks too rubbery 
[image]

I'd like to know what I could do to replicate that wet effect

EDIT: I'm using eevee, and I want to know something that could work for both cycles and eevee

I also tried to use clearcoat, normals with noise texture, but it still looks bad

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the default Blender Renderer try making the surface smoothly bumpy so there are plenty of angles to catch the light, and turn up Hardness to make the specular highlights sharper.  You could use extra lights at angles to the camera, placed here and there, with Diffuse unticked so it only gives Specular light, and if those extra lights interfere with your general lighting, you can put the lights on their own layer and tick This Layer Only, then put the gum on that layer too.  You can have more than one layer open by pressing Shift while clicking on the layers.  (You move an object to another layer with the M key, with object selected.)

Comment: *I forgot to mention that i'm using eevee and blender 2.8 , sorry

Comment: OK, so you're on your own. I haven't downloaded 2.8 yet. Sorry.